# python handle filenames with whitespace in a directory

Tags: python, tail

I have a directory with files that have whitespace in their names, I have a python script that loads these files and runs the `tail -n1` command on them, but since there is a whitespace in the name, it fails. for eg.

I have a dirctory with the following file

`data from_10_13_2014 09_00_45.json`

and my script contains the following line `line = os.popen("tail -n1 %s" % files).read()`

as of now I get the following error

```
tail: cannot open ‘/home/dataserver/Development/Test/data’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open ‘from_10_13_2014’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open ‘09_00_45.json’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

The workaround I have now is replacing whitespace with `_` is there any way I can do it without renaming the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `"tail -n1 %r"` instead, it will use the string representation of the string, ie `tail -n1 "data from_10_13_2014 09_00_45.json"`.

Or even better, switch to using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. Here you can for example use the [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function which escapes arguments automatically:

```
tail_line = subprocess.check_output(["tail", "-n1", files])
```

I'd recommend you to not use white space at all in file names, it always end up breaking scripts in the end. Maybe you can write a second script that normalizes your file names?

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I have no control over that filenames, they are generated by a sensor we use and there is no way to change it.

Comment: Ah, life is hard sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace  with  `\`  in your `files`. So a backslash + space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're depending on `popen` to parse the command line for you, and of course, it uses whitespace to do some of the parsing. A better solution is to build up a list of individual arguments so that no command line parsing has to happen.

The easiest way to do that is to use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
line = subprocess.check_output(["tail", "-n1", "/tmp/junk.py"])
```